# Multilevel Dropdown in PHP with form validations

Tags: php, jquery, forms, validation, laravel

I'm new to PHP. I want to create a form like when we select a vehicle category, another drop down should show the names of vehicles in it. I'm unable to use auto submit since the form validations are there.

For example:

```
Vehicle Number
Vehicle Type : {Light, Heavy}
Vehicle : {Car, Van} -> this should appear whenever user selects light category
Owner Name:
DL Number:
```

Since all the fields are validated, and I'm using `laravel` as framework I don't know how to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a code example? Also add an example of what you are trying to achieve. Seeing as PHP is server side it wont change the DOM once the page is loaded. That's a question for JavaScript. Think with loading all the form elements you need on the page with PHP, auto hide the ones you don't want visible right away, then use JS to listen for changes and make your DOM changes there.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! People here like to help, but you'll need to provide the following in your question. 1) What you have tried (code). 2) The current behavior. 2) The expected behavior. It's important that you ask very specific questions to get the best help.

Comment: This would be far easier with a jquery plugin google for "jquery linked select boxes".  Other wise the user will have to submit the form after each select box, for you to process them in laravel and return the right form elements.

Comment: Thank you so much sir that helped a lot.
I'm using chained select.